# How to give a permenant permission for a disk?

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, chmod

I have hdd that has been mounted to a new folder `Backup` that I created in `/media`

> /dev/sda1        15T   28K   14T   1% /media/Backup

But I am not able to create any folder and the permission is as follows
[image]

I tried to give full access by root terminal

```
root@workstation1:~# sudo chmod -R -v 777 /media/Backup/
mode of '/media/Backup/' retained as 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
mode of '/media/Backup/lost+found' changed from 0700 (rwx------) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
```

and

```
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/hdd
```

I can create the folder, but it seems I do not have full permission to this HDD, and after restarting the system, again I cannot create any folder.

I have two drives mounted to folder `/mnt`: `/mnt/hdd`, and `/mnt/ssd`;The `/media/Backup` is the mount for `/mnt/hdd`.

How can I resolve this issue by giving full access to this hdd drive?

Comment: First, don't use `/media`, you and the automounter will confuse each other. If it's for systemwide use, `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mydisk`, if it's just for your use, `mkdir -p $HOME/mnt/mydisk`. Read `man fstab sudoedit`, you can mount the disk with the UID:GID you desire.

Comment: What file system is there in the partition on the disk? If a Linux file system, you can use `chmod` to set the permissions and `chown` to set the ownership. If a Microsoft file system (NTFS, FAT32, exFAT), you set the permissions when mounting it (with mount options) according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072).